# Требования к верстальщику для Фриланса

Tags: веб-программирование, cms, backend

Всех приветствую, у меня вопрос, выручайте пожалуйста:
«Какие реальные требования к верстальщику на фрилансе, что он должен знать после азов изучения html, css, js ?»
Приведу пример: я начал изучать программирование, решил заниматься версткой на фрилансе, учусь, всё вроде получается и даже есть пару свёрстанных сайтов , но а в дальнейшем что с ними делать и что заказчики требуют зачастую?
Просто как мне кажется, я должен если не быть экспертом, то хотя бы понимать, что будет происходить с версткой дальше?
И тут в интернете неимоверно много информации и как мне показалось очень расплывчатой.
Дальше эту верстку натягивают на разные CMS, 1с битрекс, джумла, вордпресс - какую и для какого сайта выбрать так до сих пор и не понял.
Или нужно создавать свою базу данных (опять же как, на чем?) и в дальнейшем с помощью nodejs как то программировать этот сайт?
Чуть не забыл:
С хостингом я вроде бы понял всё как обстоит: зарегестрировался, купил доменное имя и сайт все видят, но опять же что бы работали все формы, в которых пользователь сайта оставляет свои контакты и т.д. это все начинает работать после того как свою вёрстку я натяну на вордпресс?

Не знаю на сколько понятно я изложил свой вопрос, но если бы кто-то помог накидать каких то статей, в какой-то правильной последовательности или возможно кто-то не пожалев своего драгоценного времени, попытался бы как-нибудь развёрнуто ответить на всё то изложенное, что я озвучил ранее, я был бы невероятно признателен.

Comment: Не шли бы вы на фриланс без опыта

Comment: @SergeyBogdanets, спасибо. 
Вот и пытаюсь как-то набраться опыта…

Comment: frontend - это видимая часть сайта. Разметку можно скачать, и любой пользователь может ее забрать себе. Backend - это невидимая, серверная часть, на которую ты отправляешь формы/запросы и там их обрабатываешь, возвращая на frontend какую-нибудь надпись допустим.


Чтобы натянуть свою верстку на вордпресс или другие CMS, тебе нужно просто прописать своим формам правильный адрес скриптов на backend'e которые будут обрабатывать формы. И вставить PHP коды вставок в frontend (по ним backend будет видеть куда в твоей разметке вставлять статьи, куда вставлять новости, куда вставлять комменты и тд)

Comment: Если хотите работать верстальщиком, то сделайте себе портфолио и ходите на собесы , пытаясь устроиться на работу. Смотрите вакансии, анализируйте требования, смотрите гайды на Ютубе, читайте статьи. Со временем придет понимание того, как всё устроено, но опять же, лучше старайтесь найти первую работу , и не лезьте на фриланс

Comment: @ЕкатеринаКорчагина Спасибо Вам большое, за столь развёрнутый ответ. Реально прочитав Ваш, ответ хоть будет понимание с чего начать знакомство со всем этим бэкендом) Может что бы я зря время не терял, вы старите моим ментором ?)

Comment: @SergeyBogdanets я понимаю, за что вы говорите и спасибо. И реально понимаю, что с практикой все придёт. Просто если говорить откровенно у меня есть работа и в целом я с неё не собираюсь уходить, а программирование я рассматриваю как дополнительный заработок ну и пускай я стану хорошим специалистом через пару лет, вроде пока не к спеху мне. В общем хочется просто иметь больше навыков по жизни и больше возможностей для заработка.

Comment: если будете рассматривать программирование как дополнительный заработок, далеко не уйдёте

Comment: @SergeyBogdanets а вот тут посмотрим ))) дайте мне ещё пол года, год и там посмотрим… ))) Вы Серёжа, обернётесь, а консультации у меня уже платные ))))))))

Comment: удачи)))))))))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frontend - это видимая часть сайта. То, что ты сверстал и разметил - это frontend

Когда ты заходишь на сайт и хочешь авторизоваться - ввести логин и пароль, попасть в личный кабинет, ты видишь frontend

Но когда ты отправляешь логин и пароль на бэкенд, там с ними что-то происходит, сервер их сверяет с базой и выводит тебе информацию из базы, если такие почта с паролем есть в базе

---

Простой пример, ты сделал index.html страничку с формой, полями ввода, и кнопкой - это frontend

```
    <html>
    <form action="http://site.com/login.php" method="post">
      <div>
        <label for="to">Укажите вашу почту:</label>
        <input name="email" id="email" value="email@email.com">
      </div>
      <div>
        <button>LOGIN</button>
      </div>
    </form>
   </html>
```

Если ты купишь домен, привяжешь домен к хостингу и зальешь на хостинг index.html файл, ты сможешь увидеть свою страничку

> это все начинает работать после того как свою вёрстку я натяну на
> вордпресс?

Чтобы форма заработала, ты должен ее привязать к backend'у, где эта форма будет обрабатываться. Где ты напишешь код и скажешь что именно сделать с этой почтой, как именно ее обработать

У нас тут есть форма, которая после нажатия на кнопку отправится на backend и там эту форму уже нужно будет обработать, чтобы что-нибудь произошло. Например записать в базу данных и потом отправить письмо

Тут ты должен заменить на свой сайт. После нажатия на кнопку, форма отправится на site.com/zapispochti.php

```
<form action="http://site.com/zapispochti.php" method="post">
```

Вот zapispochti.php - это backend, его тоже нужно сделать и разместить в корневой директории рядом с index.html

```
<?php
  $pochta = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
  print_r($pochta);
?>
```

Cейчас он просто принимает с фронтенда информацию указанную в поле email и выводит эту информацию на страницу для примера. В более сложных вариантах, он может эту почту пробить по базе например и вывести какое-то сообщение или отправить на почту письмо

---

> нужно создавать свою базу данных (опять же как, на чем?)

Изучай еще PHP для обработки запросов, которые будут приходить с фронтенда и MySQLi для баз данных

Азов html, css, js и PHP+MySQLi тебе будет достаточно, чтобы делать простые сайты, обрабатывать формы, записывать данные в базы и тд.

NodeJS тоже подойдет для backend'a

Comment: хороший ответ, но думаю его все же лучше дополнить инфой про cms системы, потому что про это есть в вопросе